# How do I get my pinterest share button to render my custom image in Django?

Tags: python, django, pinterest

I have code for sharing on pinterest in my site. The issue is that I can't get it to load a custom image.

Right now I have this where image_to_share is the path of the file:

```
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/
        ?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fkentbrew%2F6851755809%2F
        &media= {% static image_to_share %}
        &description={{photo.description}}"
        data-pin-do="buttonPin"
        data-pin-config="above">
        <img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" />
</a>
```

When I inspect element in chrome I get the path for the image as :

```
<img src="http:// /static/assets/uploaded_files/1421974839_3_art2.jpg ">
```

However, it should look like this:

```
<img src="/static/assets/uploaded_files/1421974839_3_art2.jpg">
```

How do I remove the "http://" and the trailing white space so that my image gets rendered properly?

Comment: What's the value of STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT in settings.py?

Comment: These are the values I have: STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

Comment: What do you get when you remove the space after `=` in `&media= {% static image_to_share %}`?

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the extra space before your template tag? Also you might want to do something like `{% static image_to_share as image_to_share_url %}{{ image_to_share_url|urlencode:"" }}`

Comment: @bakkal Now i get <img src="http:///static/assets/uploaded_files/1421974839_3_art2.jpg "

Comment: @Ngenator I will try this and report back

Comment: Then just prefix it with your site's domain, I think that should make it work for now

Comment: Prefixing it with my site's domain did the trick. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add your site's domain either hardcoded or with Django site

`&media={{your_site_domain}}{% static image_to_share %}`

`your_site_domain` can be `example.com` e.g.

More on Django sites: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.models.Site.domain